# OSX: NSButton with tag is not recognized

Tags: macos, cocoa, tags, nsbutton

I have a NSButton inside my cell in a NSTableView and I want to assign to it an action and a tag to have an index so I done:

```
NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"check"] )
    {
        NSButton *button = (NSButton*)[cellView viewWithTag:100];

        if (button == nil)
            NSLog(@"button is null");
        [button setTag:row];
        [button setAction:@selector(SelectRow:)];
    }
```

}

```
- (IBAction)SelectRow:(id)sender{

    NSInteger index = [sender tag];

    NSLog(@"index:%lu", index);
}
```

You can see that I have the NSButton that start with tag = 100: I set it in xib file, and I change it for its row value.
But I have a button nil because it enter in the condition.
In IOS this work fine but in OSX not... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the tag to get the right row index, then I may have another solution for you. I needed to figure out a view with a button press as well. Instead of using tags, I just asked the table view for the index of the buttons superview. For me, this was the better approach because of cells changing order..

```
- (IBAction)selectRow:(NSButton *)sender {
     NSInteger row = [_tableView rowForView:sender.superview];
     NSLog(@"index:%lu", index);
}
```

I hope I was able to help you!

Comment: Don't use `sender.superview` because it will break sooner or later (you don't own all of the views in the hierarchy). Nasty - search for the correct superview. Nice - create a custom subclass so you don't need a tag or a view search.